# Get total registered users in Ion-Auth Library

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth

Is there a method in Ion Auth library that could get total number of registered users. I know one way could be

```
$users = $this->ion_auth->users()->result();
sizeof($users);
```

But this method looks very resourceful process to get just a number. Any suggestion other than writing our own method for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$usersCount = $this->db->count_all_results('users');// assuming table name
```

[Docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results).

Or

```
$usersCount = $this->db->count_all('my_table');
```

[Docs](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html#information-about-your-database).

Answer (score 0):

There is no native method in ion auth to do this. However, it is very easy to do. Tpojka has the correct answer. I would just like to add that if by registered you mean 'active' then you can do this:

```
$this->db->where('active', '1');
$total_users = $this->db->count_all_results('your_users_table_name');
```

Further, as `users()` is an db object you can easily do this as well:

```
$total_users = $this->ion_auth->users()->num_rows();
```

and also something like this (haven't tested) but IonAuth has a where method built in:

```
$total_users = $this->ion_auth->where('active', '1')->users()->num_rows();
```